# Method “simulate” is meant to be run on 1 node. 0 found instead. - onClick

Tags: reactjs, unit-testing, jestjs

Here are  2 events using onClick  that I am trying to run a test and make sure they pass. I am using Jest and enzyme - ReactJS

What am I missing ?

event 1:

```
 <td>
 <div className={'add-header-green'}  id='test-greenheader'onClick={ ()=>{this.handleChangeOnBlur()} }>+</div>
```

Event 2

```
 <td>
 <img className='remove-header' src={closeImg} id='test-closeimg' onClick={ ()=>{this.props.removeParameters(this.props.id)} } />
```

For both tests I am getting the same error:

```
 Method “simulate” is meant to be run on 1 node. 0 found instead.
```

here are my test files for :
test1:

```js
it('should call shandleChangeOnBlur method  on click event', () => {
  // Reset info from possible previous calls of these mock functions:
  baseProps.onClick.mockClear();
  wrapper.setProps({});
  wrapper.setState({
    name: '',
    value: '',
    localState: true
  });
  wrapper.find('#test-greenheader').simulate('click', { target: { name: 'value' } });
});
```

test2:

```js
it('should call removeParameters function on button click', () => {
  baseProps.removeParameters.mockClear();
  wrapper.setProps({});
  wrapper.find('#test-closeimg').simulate('click');
  expect(baseProps.removeParameters).toHaveBeenCalled();
});
```

Comment: Can you post your completed component code? I need to know your JSX structure